# Error using ffmpeg image2pipe with phantomjs to render video from webpage screenshots

Tags: ffmpeg, phantomjs

I am trying to use phantomjs with ffmpeg to complie videos from screenshots of a webpage as described here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phantomjs/wluVGGjhL90/oGBXqh7QP44J

I have the following test.js file:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: 900, height: 800};
page.viewportSize = { width: 900, height: 800};

var url = 'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/621993/voronoi/voronoi.html';
var frames = 100;

page.open(url, function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        page.render('/dev/stdout');

        if( frames == 0 ){
            phantom.exit();
        }

        frames--;

    }, 100);
});
```

Then I run this command, taken from the link above:

```
$ phantomjs test.js |ffmpeg -c:v png -f image2pipe -r 10 -sameq -i - -y test.mp4
```

Including -sameq causes an error in ffmpeg, so I took it out and ran:

```
$ phantomjs test.js |ffmpeg -c:v png -f image2pipe -r 10 -i - -y test.mp4
```

I get the following output from ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg version 2.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 22 2013 09:14:18 with llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
  configuration: --prefix=/Volumes/Ramdisk/sw --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-libspeex --enable-libvpx --disable-decoder=libvpx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-avfilter --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-filters --enable-libgsm --arch=x86_64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      52. 38.100 / 52. 38.100
  libavcodec     55. 18.102 / 55. 18.102
  libavformat    55. 12.100 / 55. 12.100
  libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 79.101 /  3. 79.101
  libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, image2pipe, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba, 900x800 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 9:8], 10 fps, 10 tbr, 10 tbn, 10 tbc
No pixel format specified, yuv444p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 0x7f8973803800] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7f8973803800] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x7f8973803800] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 3.1, 4:4:4 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7f8973803800] 264 - core 133 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=10 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.12.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv444p, 900x800 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:8], q=-1--1, 10240 tbn, 10 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png -> libx264)
pipe:: Input/output error0 size=      65kB time=00:00:04.10 bitrate= 130.5kbits/s    
frame=   93 fps= 15 q=-1.0 Lsize=      71kB time=00:00:09.10 bitrate=  63.8kbits/s    
video:69kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 2.696543%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8973803800] frame I:1     Avg QP:15.17  size: 50212
[libx264 @ 0x7f8973803800] frame P:24    Avg QP: 8.91  size:   575
[libx264 @ 0x7f8973803800] frame B:68    Avg QP: 9.69  size:    87
[libx264 @ 0x7f8973803800] consecutive B-frames:  2.2%  0.0%  3.2% 94.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8973803800] mb I  I16..4: 64.2% 19.6% 16.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8973803800] mb P  I16..4:  2.8%  0.2%  0.1%  P16..4:  0.5%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:96.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8973803800] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  3.1%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:96.9%  L0:76.4% L1:23.6% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8973803800] 8x8 transform intra:13.9% inter:54.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8973803800] coded y,u,v intra: 7.4% 4.8% 5.2% inter: 0.1% 0.1% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8973803800] i16 v,h,dc,p: 68% 31%  2%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8973803800] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 48% 20% 32%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8973803800] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 30% 31% 20%  3%  3%  3%  5%  3%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8973803800] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8973803800] ref P L0: 91.9%  0.0%  7.4%  0.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8973803800] ref B L0: 20.5% 79.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8973803800] ref B L1: 99.9%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8973803800] kb/s:60.16
```

The output test.mp4 file is a blank 10 second video - just a black screen. From what i can tell, I am getting a **pipe:: Input/output** error from ffmpeg.

I am pretty new to ffmpeg and I have tried changing some parameters and video codecs in the ffmpeg call, but have not found a solution yet. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work by adding `-pix_fmt yuv420p` to the command:

```
$ phantomjs test.js | ffmpeg -y -c:v png -f image2pipe -r 10 -i - -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart test.mp4
```

Otherwise the output will use a [chroma subsampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling) type (`yuv444p` in this case) that is not compatible with "dumb" players like QuickTime which require `yuv420p` – YUV color space with 4:2:0 chroma subsampling.

Adding `-movflags +faststart` as an input option will allow the video to begin playing by the viewer before it is completely downloaded. Useful if the video will be viewed in a browser.

Default encoding settings for `libx264` will be used in this example resulting in H.264 video. See the [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) for more information on controlling quality and encoding speed.

Comment: Do not use [`-sameq`: it does not mean "same quality"](http://superuser.com/a/478550/110524) and has been removed from non-ancient ffmpeg (also you were using it as an input option). With libx264 use `-crf` instead as shown in the [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide). By default ffmpeg will try to avoid or minimize [chroma subsampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling), but "dumb" players like QuickTime can typical only decode YUV planar color space with 4:2:0 chroma subsampling.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! This helps me better understand ffmpeg commands

Answer (score 1):

I'm using user1690179's command but the mp4 is corrupted.
I'm able to fix it with
./ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -c copy repaired.mp4

Maybe that's because of the pipe:: Input/output error?
Maybe phantomjs doesn't end gracefully?

Answer (score 1):

i don't know much about phantomjs but if you plan on using regular node.js with ffmpeg and request/spawn i have done something similar. It incorporates the use of request to pipe in images for the snapshot url and ffmpeg through spawn for the mjpeg

[ffmpeg jpeg stream to webm only creates a file .webm with 1 frame (snapshot) or empty .webm file (mjpeg)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40560255/ffmpeg-jpeg-stream-to-webm-only-creates-a-file-webm-with-1-frame-snapshot-or/40582299#40582299)

I was having trouble with making webm files from jpeg snapshot and mjpeg stream.. but the answer provided took care of it.

I hope someone finds it useful as this question is pretty old... and perhaps this method is better at serving the task.